# weird exception in Hive : Error in semantic analysis

Tags: hadoop, hive, thrift

Maybe when you see the "Error in semantic" in the title, you consider it as syntax error? 
Of course not, I will show you what happened.

```
hive> use android;
OK
Time taken: 0.223 seconds
hive> desc tb_user_basics;
OK
col_datetime    string  
col_is_day_new  string  
col_is_hour_new string  
col_ch  string  
...
p_date  string  
p_hourmin   string  
Time taken: 0.189 seconds
hive> select count(distinct col_udid) from android.tb_user_basics where p_date>='20121001' and p_date<='20121231';
FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
hive> 
> 
> select count(distinct col_udid) from android.tb_user_basics where p_date>='20121001' and p_date<='20121231';
FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: Unable to fetch table tb_user_basics
```

I'm very sure the table does exist in the database android. After the first statement failed, it appears that the table is missing.(Even I add the db prefix in the table name)

I'm wonderring whether it's because of the volumn of data is very big, maybe you have noticed that the time range is [20121001, 20121231].
I run the command before many times, always raise this error. But if I change the contition to "p_date='20121001'", the statement can run normally. (since the volumn is smaller? )

I'm expecting your answers, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are in strict mode. One of strict mode feature is that partitions has to be specified, so this is why queries with "p_date='20121001'" in where cause are working.

Please try the non-strict mode:

```
set hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict;
```

Comment: ok, I will check that parameter. 
But in fact, if I specify the time range smaller, such as [20121001,20121005], the statement works.

Comment: I have checked that parameter,but it's already nonstrict. We have not changed it, so it remains it's default value.

Comment: You can try to set hive.metastore.client.socket.timeout. Default value is 20. Maybe it helps. Please keep us posted.

Comment: OK, I have put this parameter in hive-site.xml with value 60, in the conf directory of hive client.

Comment: I will observe that whether the same problem happends, thank you.

Comment: Are you still facing this issue or solution has been found?

Comment: Sorry, this problem doesn't happen frequently and I have been too busy these days to check this issue.

Comment: I have checked this problem again yesterday. I have turn the parameter hive.metastore.client.socket.timeout from 60 to 720, means 10 minutes.
But I still get the same error. 
And I found a phenomenon, sometimes it can run success, if I run 100 times, maybe 1 or 2 times it can success. 
So I suspect that maybe it's related to the network environment...